# Showing validation messages to user on submission of a form in Angular

Tags: angular

I am aware I can add the following to keep the Login button disabled until the form is valid:

```
<button type="submit"[disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
```

However, I prefer the user being able to click the login button and then see the required message show. Would I handle this somewhere in the login() function in the component?

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm">
        <input mdInput type="text" placeholder="Enter Email Address" id="email" 
            [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" required #em="ngModel">
        <div [hidden]="em.valid || em.pristine">
          Email is required
        </div>
        <input mdInput type="text" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password" 
            [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" required #pwd="ngModel">
        <div [hidden]="pwd.valid || pwd.pristine">
          Email is required
        </div>
    <a md-raised-button (click)="login()" color="primary">Login</a>
</form>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgForm-directive.html#!#submitted-anchor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - just create a variable to track whether Login has been clicked, and add that to the [hidden] criteria on your validation messages.

So, if the variable was called `loginClicked` then your markup would look something like:

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm">
        <input mdInput type="text" placeholder="Enter Email Address" id="email" 
            [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" required #em="ngModel">
        <div [hidden]="em.valid || (em.pristine && !loginClicked)">
          Email is required
        </div>
        <input mdInput type="text" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password" 
            [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" required #pwd="ngModel">
        <div [hidden]="pwd.valid || (em.pristine && !loginClicked)">
          Email is required
        </div>
    <a md-raised-button (click)="login()" color="primary">Login</a>
</form>
```

This does mean that you need to ensure that the form values are valid in the Login() method. This can be done by referencing the form in your component code:

```
@ViewChild('loginForm') loginForm: NgForm;
```

Or, (much easier in all but the simplest situations) you could use Model Driven/Reactive Forms, which allow much simpler in-code interaction. There are great examples on the angular.io documentation page:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html

Comment: So I created a boolean variable in my component called loginClicked and set it to false by default. In the login() function when the button is clicked I set it to true. Also applied the html you gave. Not sure how this would work if my login() function sets loginClicked to true and then instantly sends the data out tot he api. I am looking for the login() function to not be called if fields are not valid.

Comment: I should have mentioned that - in your Login() function you should do a form validity check before taking any action.